# rustc shows downstream crates may implement trait

Tags: rust

```rust
pub mod traits {
    pub trait Foo<T> {}
    pub trait Bar<T> {}
    impl<T, U: Foo<T>> Bar<T> for U {}
}
pub struct Test {}
impl<T> traits::Bar<T> for Test {}

fn main() {}
```

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b03d74ef8fa382abed38a4b11fee984)

it shows :

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `traits::Bar<_>` for type `Test`
 --> src/main.rs:8:1
  |
5 |     impl<T, U: Foo<T>> Bar<T> for U {}
  |     ------------------------------- first implementation here
...
8 | impl<T> traits::Bar<T> for Test {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ conflicting implementation for `Test`
  |
  = note: downstream crates may implement trait `traits::Foo<_>` for type `Test`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

is that a feature or a bug?

Comment: This is not a bug. Is this a feature? I don't know. Downstream crates may have `struct Baz; impl Foo<Baz> for Test {}`.

Comment: Yah, I stumbled across this already myself on numerous occasions. It's annoying, but the logical consequence from the fact that Rust's `impl` declarations are always unique.

Comment: Also, do you have another question besides `is this a feature or a bug?`, or was this all you wanted to know? Seems like a weird question to spend an entire stack overflow post on :)

Comment: @Finomnis I just wonder why i have just implemented Bar<T> for Test for one time.And i haven't implement Foo for Test.So The T in first impl isn't include Foo,but it still shows conflict implementation. Maybe i misunderstand the meaning of "Downstream crates"?

Comment: "Downstream crates" means "other crates that use your crate". Users of your crate could define what Chayim wrote, which would cause a collision.

Comment: @Finomnis Thanks....but that is more puzzling. the other crate ,actually cant implement a trait in my crate for a struct in my crate too due to orphan principle. How could that happen?

Comment: The other crate has to own at least one of the pieces to `impl` a trait, and the piece it can own is the generic `T`.

Comment: I honestly didn't know that until 5 minutes ago either, I would have guessed that owning a generic isn't enough, but it seems like it is. What's the background there, @ChayimFriedman?

Comment: @Finomnis Background to what?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Why a crate can implement `Foo<T>` if all it owns is the `T` part, I would have expected that because if a crate owns neither `Test` nor `Foo`, it can't implement `Foo<MyType> for Test`

Comment: @Finomnis https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/implementations.html#orphan-rules. Specifically "At least one of the types `T0..=Tn` must be a local type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential collision:

```rust
impl<T, U: Foo<T>> Bar<T> for U {}
```

This means that all types that implement `Foo` also implement `Bar`.

This, however:

```rust
impl<T> traits::Bar<T> for Test {}
```

means that `Test` implements `Bar`. The problem here is that `Test` **could** implement `Foo` for `T` types not yet known in this crate.

Like, if another crate defines a type `MyStruct`, and implements `Foo<MyStruct>`:

```rust
struct MyStruct {}

impl Foo<MyStruct> for Test {}
```

that's perfectly fine from the standpoint of the other crate. It creates the ambiguity, though, that the compiler now doesn't know which implementation of `Bar<MyStruct>` should use:

- `impl<MyStruct, U: Foo<MyStruct>> Bar<MyStruct> for U {}` with `U` being `Test`
- `impl<T> traits::Bar<T> for Test {}` with `T` being `MyStruct`

To avoid this ambiguity, the compiler disallows you from writing that code in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!. you remind me that Foo<MyStruct> is actually can implement for structs that defined in other crate.